# Read the entered phone number Before SMS sent from Facebook Kit account

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio, account-kit

How can I read the user entered "Phone number" in the SMS login field from Facebook account kit? I am using facebook kit account SDK to verify the user phone number and want to read the user-entered phone number before sent OTP to my number.

I am using Android and want to just check with my server that this number already registered or not.

Comment: Account Kit only provides verified phone numbers (or emails) at the end of the Account Kit flow so they are only returned after the verification step is complete.

Answer (score 0):

AccountKit is an end-to-end solution for logging in with a phone number so there is no way of getting that phone number before it is logged in. One option is to let AccountKit complete the login flow and then check the number on your backend server post-login.